# Dynamically add input for more than one array

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to add more than one array input and a button that will create new inputs.

I have four arrays `vm.work_place[]`, `vmwork_year_start[]`, `vm.work_yead_end[]`, `vm.work_why_left[]`. What I want is to create new input everytime I click on a button, and another button that will remove the input.

```
<button ng-click="vm.work_place.push(' ');vm.work_year_start.push(' ');vm.work_yead_end.push(' ');vm.work_why_left.push(' ');">Add row</button>

<tr ng-repeat="x in vm.work_place">
    <td>
        <input name="work_place[]" ng-model="vm.work_place[$index]"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="work_place[]" ng-model="vm.work_year_start[$index]"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="work_place[]" ng-model="vm.work_yead_end[$index]"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="work_place[]" ng-model="vm.work_why_left[$index]"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button ng-click="vm.work_place.splice(index, 1);vm.work_year_start.splice(index, 1);vm.work_yead_end.splice(index, 1);vm.work_why_left.splice(index, 1);">Remove row</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

But the problem is that the code above gives me a `ngRepeat:dupes` Error when I click on the add new row button.

How can I create more than One input at the same time, ie. to add an Item on all four arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ngRepeat:dupes` this error comes when you iterate in a array with duplicate values.So i guess you would be getting error while adding row second times. because already **vm_worksapace** has `' '` as data when first row is added and when you click again `' '` is added again so there is duplicate value now and `ng-repeat` will give you eror.
To make this work with duplicate value

**replace**  `<tr ng-repeat="x in vm.work_place" >` **with** `<tr ng-repeat="x in vm.work_place track by $index" >`

Comment: I thought `track by $index` is optionally and only used to identify the loop iterator variable name.